# Where is my formula false??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, project-euler

I wrote a formula that returned how many numbers in a given row of pascals triangle are divisible by a given prime.

This formula was created to answer https://projecteuler.net/problem=148.

I was able to determine that my formula works (using the number 7) against the first 82,000 rows of Pascal's Triangle, but I am still unable to plug in the right answer.

I think that somewhere between rows 82,000 and 1 billion my formula goes wrong, if anyone can help me find out where (what row number), or if anyone can help me fix the formula , i'd greatly appreciate it.

(Extra / Useless info: When looking into this I noticed that if you black out all the numbers divisible by the given prime in the triangle, it turns into Sierpinski's triangle, using that pattern i was able to create the formula)

r = row number

p = prime number

if r < p return 0

c = p^floor(log(r) / log(p)) (largest exponent of p that does not exceed r)

a = r % c

b = floor(r / c)

f(r,p) = b(c-a-1) + (f(a,p)*(b+1))

Comment: It's conceivable that floating point error is giving you a problem, anywhere you are depending on the result of a floor() to be perfect.  You probably should be using an integer-only solution that takes advantage of [Legendre's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml) instead.

Comment: i say floor on here because when programming, 2/3 = 0, and 14/6 = 2. I only get integer values back on there, so I said floor on here to make sure everyone else was also only getting integer values, but I see how adding that on there could skew the results others would get.

Comment: You're using $\left\lfloor \frac{\log r}{\log p} \right\rfloor$ too, which could be off by one in many cases.

Comment: Hmm, log base p of r (log r / log p) has worked for me so far, but what would be a better way to get the exponent of p that is closest to , or equal to r? (Also, if you are the one who removed the pascals triangle tag on here, can you please add it back?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, there was nothing wrong with this after all, I finally got the right answer, I was just looking at the wrong information.